# A SQL Server function to generate of sequential numbers

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, sequences, clr-hosting

I would like to have a SQL Server function `dbo.GetNextNumber()`, which would generate sequential numbers for each call. As far as I understand this is impossible with a native T-SQL function as SQL Server insists the functions has to be deterministic. But, if you could show me a native T-SQL function that does this would really make my day.

I thought perhaps this could be possible to write using a CLR function. As CLR functions are static, the sequence numbers need to be stored in the calling context of the set operation, as storing it as a static variable would result in several connections using the same sequence, resulting in not-so-sequential numbers. I do not know enough about embedded CLR to see if set operation's (select, update, delete, insert) calling context is reachable from the CLR side.

At the end of the day, the following query

```
select dbo.GetNextNumber() from sysobjects
```

must return the result

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

It is OK if another function call to reset the context is necessary like

```
exec dbo.ResetSequenceNumbers()
```

To prevent some misunderstandings and reduce the chances of wasting your time answering wrong question, please note that I am not looking for an ID generation function for a table and I am aware of some hacks (albeit using a proc not a function) that involves some temp tables with identity columns. The `ROW_NUMBER()` function is close but it also does not cut.

Thanks a lot for any responses

Kemal

P.S. It is amazing that SQL Server does have a built-in function for that. A function (provided that it cannot be used in joins and where clauses) is really easy to do and extremely useful, but for some reason it is not included.

Comment: rather than ask for a "sql server function dbo.GetNextNumber(), " tell us the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: You could use a "helper" table with just a single `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column and grab the value after each INSERT (using `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`), or you can wait for SQL Server "Denali" (2011 / 2012) which will have [SEQUENCES as native database objects](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) for exactly this purpose

Comment: SQL-Server functions do not have to be deterministic.  In some cases, a deterministic function is required (computed columns, for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have implemented the CLR sequence based on my article related to the calculation of Running Totals, you can achieve the same using the **`ROW_NUBER()`** function.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function requires the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause, however there is a nice workaround how to avoid sorting due to the `ORDER BY`. You cannot put an expression in the order by, but you can put `SELECT aConstant` there. So you can easily achieve number generating using below statement.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber,
    *
FROM aTable
```

Answer (score 2):

In the next version of SQL Server you can use a SEQUENCE to do this. In earlier versions it's easy enough to do by inserting to a separate "sequence table" (a table with only an IDENTITY column) and then retrieving the value with the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function. You won't be able to do that in a function but you can use a stored procedure.

Comment: this will not do as sql server does not allow encapsulating this logic in a function. Perhaps, I should create a CLR function to do just that. But this would be a hack, not an elegant solution

Comment: I think what everyone would like to know is why it's so important to you to do this in a function rather than a procedure. You are trying to use functions for something they were not intended for.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give more information about why `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't cut it?  In the specific example you give, `ROW_NUMBER()` (with appropriate clarification of `OVER(ORDER BY)`) certainly seems to match your criteria.

But there are certainly cases where `ROW_NUMBER()` might not be useful, and in those cases, there are usually other techniques.

Perhaps having this general function seems useful to you, but in most cases, I find a solution better tailored to the problem at hand is a better idea than a general purpose function which ends up causing more difficulties - like a leaky abstraction you are constantly working around.  You specifically mention the need to have a reset function.  No such thing is needed with `ROW_NUMBER()`, given that it has the `OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY)` which allow you to specify the grouping.

Comment: row_number requires an over predicate which forces you to specify an order by clause. In some of my cases, I need that function over a temp table whose natural order is significant. And, in some other cases, the columns that could be specified there is not known until runtime, forcing you to use dynamic sql. And finally, you have to wrap everything into a sub-query to be able to use the value of row_number(). Not so nice

Comment: @Kemal Erdogan There is no such thing as a natural order in SQL.  If you are relying on insertion order or clustered index or anything else, there is no guaranteed order without an ORDER BY.  While you may happen to get an order and it may seem reliable, there is nothing guaranteed without an ORDER BY.  SQL is a declarative language, and without a declaration or your desires, nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: There is indeed no such thing as natural order in sql theory. But simplest and most natural way of implementing inserts for heap tables is just keeping the insertion order intact. That's why microsoft never changed that and I see no reason for it be changed. So, in practice, there is such thing as natural order

Comment: @Kemal Erdogan Just because the insertion order is intact in the table's page structure means nothing about returning the values later or when joined to other things or put through any operations.  Bluntly, I will say again that relying on rows to be pulled out later in any order without an `ORDER BY` is irresponsible.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387008/when-i-insert-rows-into-a-sql-server-2005-table-will-the-order-be-preserved http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx

Comment: Dear Cade Roux,
I qualified my response with "for heap tables", I cannot really know how the indexed tables work as there are numerous ways to optimize the tree, balancing needs, etc. which might return rows in other sequence (well, usually by clustered index order) But, you are right, generally speaking, it cannot be relied upon

Comment: @Kemal Erdogan What about a heap table with an ordinary non-clustered index which is covering for your particular query so that the heap table is never actually accessed?  So now we're down to un-indexed heap tables that are not joined to anything else in your query.

Comment: @Kemal, Even in a heap table there is no such thing as a "natural order". Heap tables do not preserve the order of insertion and certainly not in any way that you can take advantage of in a subsequent SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Denali has a new sequence structure for developers
It is easy to manage and maintain sequence numbers in SQL Server after Denali
You can find details in [Sequence Numbers in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/create-sequence-sql-server-2011-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)

For other versions than Denali, you can use Sequence Tables.
Here is a sample for [Sequence Table in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-instead-of-trigger-with-sequence-table.aspx)
For reading sequence number from sequence table, you should insert dummy records from this auto identity enabled sql table

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2022 there is a new operator to address this:

`GENERATE_SERIES ( start, stop [, step ] )`

For full details, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16